# X-Lite Asterisk Failed to establish call - Forbidden number

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to setup caller ID spoofing using asterisk running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ0czppbamo and I am currently stuck at 29:20. The problem is when I attempt to call the test number 12120001234 given to me by GoTrunk, X-Lite throws the error "Failed to establish call - Forbidden number". My sip.conf file is as follows:

```
[general]
allowguest=no
context=default
bindport=5060
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm
allow=g723
allow=g726
allow=speex

; replace INBOUND_SIP_USERNAME and INBOUND_SIP_PASSWORD
; with your Inbound SIP Registration credentials
register => ####:#####

[201]
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
username=201
password=####
qualify=yes
nat=force_rport,comedia

[202]
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
username=202
password=######
qualify=yes
nat=force_rport,comedia

[trunk]
type=peer
host=eu.st.ssl7.net  ; Europe POP
;host=amn.st.ssl7.net ; North America POP
context=from-trunk
qualify=yes
defaultuser=#####
remotesecret=#####
```

I would also like to add that I have never setup caller ID spoofing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just means your provider not allow you do spoofing. Not all providers allow that. Considering latest changes in USA law most of providers should not allow.